# How can I get the actual error message in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, wamp

I'm getting this error message:

> An Error Was Encountered
>
> The action you have requested is not allowed.

But I can't find anything in the logs and there's nothing being displayed on the page. This happens after I submit a form. How can I get the actual technical error message?

For the record, this form/page does work just fine on LAMP and only displays this message as I'm testing it on my WAMP machine. Really confusing.

Comment: can you briefly explain how that happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your options are to set `csrf_protection` to `FALSE` or use the `form_open` function

See http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/security.html:

> You can enable csrf protection by opening your
>   application/config/config.php file and setting this:
>
> $config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE; If you use the form helper the
>   form_open() function will automatically insert a hidden csrf field in
>   your forms.

The error is coming from line 205 in `system/core/Security.php`

```
public function csrf_show_error()
{
    show_error('The action you have requested is not allowed.');
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This did end up being a csrf issue and customizing the error message helped.